# a program that produces a reciept based on a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, printing

A program that allows a user to enter any number and, if that number is part of a pre made dictionary, would ask the user how much of that item, and then output a receipt of:

```
12345670 apple 2 2.00
total cost of orders       2.00
```

My dictionary would be

```
items = {'12345670' : {'name' : 'apple', 'price' : 1},
         '87654325' : {'name' : 'orange', 'price' : 1}}
print("Hi There! Welcome to sSpecialists!")
print("To start shopping, note down what you want to buy and how much of it")
print("Here are the purchasable items")
print("~~~~~")
print("12345670 is a hammer (£4.50)")
print("87654325 is a screw driver (£4.20)")
print("96385272 is a pack of 5 iron screws (£1.20)")
print("74185290 is pack of 20 100mm bolts (£1.99)")
print("85296374 is a pack of 6 walkers crisps (£1)")
print("85274198 is haribo pack (£1)")
print("78945616 is milk (£0.88)")
print("13246570 is a bottle of evian water (£0.99)")
print("31264570 is kitkat original (£0.50)")
print("91537843 is a cadbury bar (£1)")
print('88198101 is sausage, price is(£6.75)')
print('88198118 is stuffed shells, price is(£7.75)')
print('88198125 is manicotti, price is(£7.75)')
print('88198132 is chicken & broccoli pasta, price is(£11.00)')
print('88198149 is baked ravioli, price is(£5.00)')
print('88198156 is ribs & hand-breaded shrimp, price is(£8.40)')
print('88198163 is hickory bourbon-glazed pork chop, price is(£9.99)')
print('88198170 is grilled chicken & crab cake combo, price is(£12.75)')
print('88198187 is double decker chicken, price is(£7.99)')
print('88198194 is grilled salmon, price is(£10.00)')
print('88198200 is herb-crusted tilapia , price is(£4.00)')
print("~~~~~")
possibleOrders = {'12345670' : {'name' : 'hammer', 'price' : 4.50},
         '87654325' : {'name' : 'screwDriver', 'price' : 4.20},
         '96385272' : {'name' : 'packOf5IronnScrews', 'price' : 1.20},
         '74185290' : {'name' : 'packOf200mmBolts', 'price' : 1.99},
         '85296374' : {'name' : 'packOf6WalkersCrisps', 'price' : 1},
         '85274198' : {'name' : 'hariboPack', 'price' : 1},
         '78945616' : {'name' : 'milk', 'price' : 0.88},
         '13246570' : {'name' : 'bottleOfEvianWater', 'price' : 0.99},
         '31264570' : {'name' : 'kitkatOriginal', 'price' : 0.50},
         '88198101' : {'name' : 'sausage', 'price' : 6.75},
         '88198118' : {'name' : 'stuffedShells', 'price' : 7.75},
         '88198125' : {'name' : 'manicotti', 'price' : 7.75},
         '88198132' : {'name' : 'chicken&broccoliPasta', 'price' : 11.00},
         '88198149' : {'name' : 'baked_ravioli', 'price' : 5.00},
         '88198156' : {'name' : 'ribs&handBreadedShrimp', 'price' : 8.40},
         '88198163' : {'name' : 'hickoryBourbonGlazedPorkChop', 'price' : 9.99},
         '88198170' : {'name' : 'grilledChicken&crabCakeCombo', 'price' : 12.75},
         '88198187' : {'name' : 'doubleDeckerChicken', 'price' : 7.99},
         '88198200' : {'name' : 'herbCrustedTilapia', 'price' : 4.00},
         '91537843' : {'name' : 'cadburyBar', 'price' : 1}}
print("Alright, now start typing what you want to order")
print(" ")
price = 0
full_list = " "
chos_items = []
while full_list != "":
    print(" ")
    full_list = input("Type: ")
    if full_list == 'end':
        break
    item = int(full_list)
    amount = int(input("Amount: "))
    item = int(full_list)
    if full_list in possibleOrders:
        orders = print("{}    {:>5}    (£{:0.2f})".format(full_list,     possibleOrders[full_list]['name'], possibleOrders[full_list]['price']))
        if orders != "":
            chos_items.append(full_list)
        price  = int(amount) * (possibleOrders[full_list]['price']) + price
        print("Subtotal is currently at "+str(price))
print("Your subtotal is: " +str(price))
receipt = input("Would you like to view your receipt?: ")
if receipt == 'yes':
    print(chos_items)
```

This is my code, I need to save the user inputs it, and translate it's name, to it corresponding number in my pre made dictinary

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this assignment? What problems are you facing?

Comment: Yes, however, when I store user inputs, I want to display its 'name' and quantity sold based on the pre made dictionary

Comment: Please show us your code. You should also show the expected output _(which you already have, but isn't very clear)_ and actual output so that we can help you.

Comment: Alright there is my code

Answer (score 0):

To check if the user entry is in the dictionary, you can both do `if entry in items.keys()` or `items.get(entry)`. The first will check if there's that entry in the dictionary. Then, it's trivial to get the value of that key. The second will return the value of that key if it is the dict, else it will return none.

Proposed solution:

```
available_products = {
    '1234': {
        'name': 'hammer',
        'price': 4.50
        },
    '4321': {
        'name': 'screw driver',
        'price' : 4.20
        }
}

print("----------------------------------------")

for key, product in available_products.items():
    print("{key} - {name} ${price}".format(key=key, name=product['name'], price=product['price']))

print("----------------------------------------")

print("Alright, now start typing what you want to order. \n")

list_of_products = []
subtotal = 0

while(True):
    entry = input('Type: ')

    if entry == 'end':
        break

    product = available_products.get(entry)

    if product:
        print('{key} {name} ${price}'.format(key=entry, name=product['name'], price=product['price']))

        amount = int(input('How many? '))
        subtotal += amount * product['price']
        list_of_products.append((entry, amount))

        print('Subtotal is {}'.format(subtotal))
    else:
        print("Product is not available")

print('Your receipt is:')

for entry, amount in list_of_products:
    product = available_products.get(entry)

    print("{key} - {amount}x {name} - ${price}".format(key=entry, amount=amount, name=product['name'], price=product['price']))
print("Total price is {} \n".format(subtotal))
```

Comment: What if I store multiple inputs

Comment: Like, the user inputs several entries? Well, in that case you will have to preprocess the user input to separate them into independent keys and it depends on how you are dealing with external inputs. If you are using the raw_input of Python 2 or input() of Python 3, you will have a string that will have to be separated.In the end you are probably reaching a list of entries and you will have to do something like `for entry in entries` and do what I said previously. Try adding some code snippet to your question to give us a clue of what you are doing. It will help us to help you :)

Comment: What would this string be, I am using 3.5

Comment: The `input("Type: ")` will make everything the user enter a string. This is what you need to preprocess. You are casting it into a int. The issue here is if the user tries to write anything that can't be casted into int. Like, if one writes 1234, 5678, 9876. You will have a string like "1234, 5678, 9876". You should be preprocessing that.

Comment: Because the input will be on a loop the user can input into that variable multiple times, so if I save it, to a list, later, I won't be able to hash it

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is your doubt. I ran your code to see the expected behaviur and rewrote it the way I proposed. It works fine. I'm editing my answer to include the proposed solution. Check it and see if you can understand what I've done. If you still have doubts, comment here and I'll see if I can help.